# Difference between anhören und hören

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Ich habe diese Frage gefunden:
"Wollen wir uns die Oper zusammen *_*?"
a) hören
b) anhören
Aber was ist der Unterschied zwischen anhören und hören?!

Comment: "hören" ist passiv (vergleiche Englisch "to hear"), "anhören" etwas das man aktiv tut (Englisch  "to listen"). Anhören impliziert ein gewisses Maß an Konzentration (und wäre daher in diesem Fall die richtige Wahl).

Comment: Es scheint so, dass du schon wieder eine Frage gestellt hast, die hier schon einmal gefragt wurde. Du kannst dies vermeiden, indem du die Suchfunktion bemühst, oder dir Vorschläge ähnlicher Fragen durchliest, die in der rechten Leiste erscheinen, wenn du deine Frage formulierst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richtig ist:

> Wollen wir uns die Oper zusammen anhören?

### etwas hören

hören = engl. "to hear". Man hört das Geräusch des Straßenverkehrs, man hört wie sich Menschen an der Bushaltestelle unterhalten und man hört das Ticken der Uhr. Das sind alles Vorgänge, die man eher ungewollt erlebt. Man hatte nicht das Bedürfnis diese Wahrnehmungen zu machen.

### sich etwas anhören

anhören = engl. "to listen". Man hört sich ein Musikstück an, man hört sich die Rede des Präsidenten an und man hört sich an, was ein Zeuge auszusagen hat. Das sind Vorgänge, bei denen man die akustische Wahrnehmung ganz bewusst einsetzt, um etwas zu erfahren oder etwas zu genießen. Hier wird ein Bedürfnis befriedigt.

Ein Uhrmacher kann sich aber auch das Ticken einer Uhr anhören (also gewollt und bewusst wahrnehmen), um festzustellen, ob die Uhr in Ordnung ist.